# Measure invariant under circle maps

Tags: gr.group-theory, ergodic-theory, amenability

Consider continuous bijections (may even assume these are homeomorphisms or diffeomorphisms if it helps) from the circle onto itself given by $x \mapsto x + s_i(x)$  where $i = 1,2$ or $3$. (I'm identifying the circle with $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.)

The basic question would be, is there an measure which is invariant under these bijections? (i.e. under the monoid generated by these maps)

I'm fairly sure the answer is negative most of the time: 
take $s_1$ to be an irrational constant and $s_2$ not to be constant (the only invariant measure for $s_1$ is the uniform measure).

But there are also conditions which would ensure the existence of such a measure, e.g.:

- if $s_1$ and $s_2$ are both rational constants and $s_3$ is arbitrary [this boils down to the fact that a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ is amenable]
- another example would be that $s_2$ and $s_3$ already belong to the monoid generated by $s_1$.

**Question:** Are there other conditions which ensure the existence of an invariant measure (on the circle)? [Or is the action of these monoids almost never amenable?]

As a side note, the $s_i$ in my problem are such that, for all $x$, $s_1(x) < s_2(x) < s_3(x)$ and $s_i(x) \in [a_i,b_i]$ where $a_i >0$ and $b_i < \tfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: A continuous permutation of a compact space is a self-homeomorphism, so this is just a question about subgroups of $\mathrm{Homeo}(R/Z)$ generated by three elements. Subgroups of $\mathrm{Homeo}(R/Z)$ preserving a Borel probability measure (I assume this is what you call measure, otherwise the counting measure is invariant) are well-understood and very restricted (I'd need to track the precise statement).

Comment: Some information can be found in [Navas' survey: Groups of circle diffeomorphisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607481). For instance, see Theorem 2.3.2, Exercise 2.3.11, Corollary 3.2.6.

Comment: @Ycor Indeed, I meant probability measure. Many thanks for the reference(s). It seems that (up to conjugacy) the options I listed cover already most of the (simple) positive cases.

Comment: Probably rather up to semi-conjugacy. Indeed, let $f$ be a homeo with no fixed point, with some open interval $I$ such that the $f^n(I)$ are pairwise disjoint. Then the whole wreath product $G=\mathrm{Homeo}^+(I)\rtimes \langle f\rangle$ acts with an invariant proba (supported by the complement of $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbf{Z}} f^n(I)$)  and $G$ is not amenable (it has free subgroups).